# Swagger Editor how to set a basePath per tag?

Tags: swagger-editor

I'm newbie with Swagger editor (I'm trying the web version), I need to set different basePath param per group of endpoints.

For example

I have an host https://myhost.com and endpoint grouped by different basepath:

```
https://myhost.com/rest
https://myhost.com/auth
https://myhost.com/report
```

It would be useful to have a basePath set per Tag, is it possible? There are others ways or solutions to group the endpoints with different basePath?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Override “host” and “basePath” at the “/{path}” level](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37157721/113116).