# OpenAPI multiple servers with different apis?

Tags: api, documentation, openapi

i want to define multiple servers with different API's in one openAPI file, is this possible?

What I mean:

```yaml
servers:
  - url: http://server1
paths:
  /abc:

servers:
  - url: http://server2
paths:
  /completely_different_api (with different media types):
```

So I want to have server 1 and server 2 with different API's in one file, so that I can select the server and the API's will change automatically.

Is that possible?
Unfortunately I have not found anything

Or is there an alternative to OpenAPI that I can do this with?

Comment: Does this answer your question? -- [Override "host" and "basePath" at the "/{path}" level](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37157721/113116)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define `servers` at the path or operation level.